# Command Line Options for a script

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, scripting

```
$ cat test15.sh  
#!/bin/bash  
# extracting command line options as parameters  
#  
echo  
while [ -n "$1" ]  
do  
    case "$1" in  
    -a) echo "Found the -a option" ;;  
    -b) echo "Found the -b option" ;;  
    -c) echo "Found the -c option" ;;  
     *) echo "$1 is not an option" ;;
esac  
shift  
done  
$  
$ ./test15.sh -a -b -c -d

Found the -a option  
Found the -b option  
Found the -c option  
-d is not an option 
$
```

`-d` represents debug or delete as a command line option. So why is it not   an option when we included it in options on command line for some script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-d` represents whatever it is programmed to represent, which will not necessarily be delete or debug.  In `curl` for example `-d` is the option for data. In your script `-d` is not a valid option.  Your options are `-a`, `-b`, and `-c`.  All of which essentially do nothing.

```
while [ -n "$1" ]  
do  
    case "$1" in  
        -a) echo "Found the -a option" ;;  
        -b) echo "Found the -b option" ;;  
        -c) echo "Found the -c option" ;;  
         *) echo "$1 is not an option" ;;
    esac  
shift  
done
```

---

To add support for `-d` you must add it to your case statement like the following:

```
while [ -n "$1" ]  
do  
    case "$1" in  
        -a) echo "Found the -a option" ;;  
        -b) echo "Found the -b option" ;;  
        -c) echo "Found the -c option" ;;  
        -d) echo "Found the -d option" ;;
         *) echo "$1 is not an option" ;;
    esac  
shift  
done
```

---

A better way to handle command line options would be with `getopts` which would look something like the following:

```
while getopts abcd opt; do 
    case $opt in
        a) echo "Found the -a option";;
        b) echo "Found the -b option";;
        c) echo "Found the -c option";;
        d) echo "Found the -d option";;
        *) echo "Error! Invalid option!" >&2;;
    esac
done
```

`abcd` is the list of expected arguments.
`a` - check for option `-a` without parameters; gives error on unsupported options.
`a:` - check for option `-a` with parameter; gives errors on unsupported options.  The parameter would be set to the `OPTARG` variable.
`abcd` - check for options `-a`, `-b`, `-c`, `-d`; gives errors on unsupported options.
`:abcd` - check for options `-a`, `-b`, `-c`, `-d`; silences errors on unsupported options.

`opt` is the variable the current parameter will be set to (also used in the case statement)

Comment: Using `getopts` is preferred as it also stops processing at the first non-option argument (or at `--`), which makes it easier to handle e.g. file operands too.